# Вывод массива String в Label Windows forms C++

Tags: winforms, строки, c++-cli, label

Стараюсь сделать вывод массива типа string через цикл в Label. Аналогичным образом цифры выводятся, а вот при попытке запихнуть в цикл стринговый массив, получаю ошибку "отсутствует оператор "+", соответствуэщий этим операндам".
Вот, как объявлен мой массив:

```
    std::vector<std::string> cities{ "Dnepr", "Krivoy rog", "Novomoskovsk", "Pokrovskoe"}
```

А вот, как пытаюсь его вывести:

```
for (int bt = 0;bt < routes[0].size();bt++) {   //проверка вывода в label маршрута
            label1->Text = label1->Text + cities[routes[0][bt]] + "-";
        }
```

Я поняла, что здесь нужно как-то преобразовать стринговый массив, погуглила, но так и не поняла, как это правильно сделать.

Comment: Передайте от меня вашим преподам, которые заставляют учить C++/CLI, что они [_вырезано цензурой_]. Этот язык не предназначен для написания приложений. У него одна цель: быть _клеем_ для управляемого и неуправляемого кода.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov чел, Qt просто так придумали? С++ еще как предназначен. А вот использовать win forms это [вырезано цензурой].

Comment: @Lofectr - где вы видите хоть слово против Qt или C++? Читайте внимательно: речь о языке C++/CLI. Это отличный язык (единственный в своём роде), но он не предназначен для написания _приложений_. Только для написания обёрток (wrapper).

Comment: @Lofectr - и, да, WinForms превосходная платформа. Для своего времени.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не знал, что C++/CLI это отдельный язык

Comment: @Lofectr - к сожалению, преподы в учебных заведениях об этом не знают. Я уже много лет воюю (в комментариях с дивана) против его преподавания начинающим.

Comment: Попробуйте `label1->Text = label1->Text +  label1->Text (cities[routes[0][bt]].data()) + "-";`

Comment: @ARHovsepyan подчеркивает label1 и выдает "вызов объекта типа дескриптора без соответствующего оператора operator() или без функций преобразования в тип указателя на функцию"

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov преподам обязательно передам, но я не совсем поняла, с чего вы взяли, что я пишу приложение. Я использую формы всего лишь чтобы немного красивее представить то, что уже написано в консоли. Все мои цели прекрасно можно выполнить на C++/CLI, но в данном случае, я просто не знаю правильного синтаксиса (но я знаю, что это выполнимо)

Comment: `std::string` (C++) и `System::String^` (C++/CLI) - два совершенно разных типа строк из совершенно разных платформ. Свойство `Text` имеет тип `System::String^`. Можно погуглить, как один тип преобразовать во второй (постоянно его задают). Но правильнее будет использовать [List<T>](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.0) вместо `vector<T>`.

Comment: Вы пишете именно приложение на языке, непредназначенном для этого. Если у вас есть какой-то код на C++ и хочется сделать к нему GUI на платформе .NET, то сваяйте формочку на C#. А на C++/CLI следует сделать лишь обёртку над библиотекой.